# Selenium ChromeDriver not interacting with Chrome Print Dialog

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to web scraping, and I have recently tried to create a web scraper that prints out my online Calendar. I have been able to work out how to get to the print prompt with *Selenium*, but I cannot interact with the actual print window when I try to programmatically click the **Print** & **Cancel** buttons.

The print prompt does take a second or two to load, and I already have the print window selected as the current window by Webdriver (accomplished using the below code)

```
whandles = driver.window_handles
print("About to switch window handle to print window, should be: " + whandles[1])
driver.switch_to.window(whandles[1])
```

But when I try:

```
printBtnFinal = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,'action-button'))).click()
```

nothing happens, the program times out (I'm assuming because the element never was found).

How can I successfully interact with the Chrome Print Window?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Chrome Print Window` how do I open this ?

Comment: If you're using google or Outlook calendar, they typically override the calendar with a separate print screen.  I am using Outlook, and when I hit **print** in the top right corner of my Outlook Calendar, I'm taken to a config screen. If I again hit **print** on this screen, I am finally on the **Chrome Print Window**.

Comment: I must be missing something, I have a outlook open in my google chrome, But still I am not able to figure out where is the print in outlook ?

Comment: Are you in Outlook Calendar?

Comment: No I am at `https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox`

Comment: Ah I see, open Outlook Calendar: https://outlook.live.com/calendar/

Comment: When I used the url that you've given, it asked me for my creds. that was weird, cause my session cookies are already stored, also after providing my creds it redirected me to inbox from there I see a calendar option, and that has a link https://outlook.office365.com/calendar/view/month

Comment: Yeah, Outlook is a bit weird like that. You should be in the right place using that URL.

Comment: If this URL is okay with you to replicate your issue outlook.office365.com/calendar/view/month  I can look further into your issue.

Comment: URL works for me, it should have the print in the top right corner.

Comment: oh well yes, it does have. Are you able to click on the print  which is in the top right corner ?

Comment: Yes, that works, and the print in the bottom of the next screen. Final print doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Explanation

You do not need to `switch to Print Modal pop up`. Because it is not a `new windows/tab` neither it is in `frame`. So switching is the culprit here.

### Solution

I would recommend you to use `WebDriverWait` which is an explicit waits in `Selenium` library.

to `click` on `Print` which is in top right corner use this `xpath` and `code` :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button"))).click()
```

Once this is clicked you'd see a `new pop up` with `Print` and `Cancel` `button`.

to click on Print in the pop up, the below code should help you past the issue that you've been facing.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button[contains(@class,'action')]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://outlook.live.com/owa/?state=1&redirectTo=aHR0cHM6Ly9vdXRsb29rLmxpdmUuY29tL2NhbGVuZGFyLw&nlp=1")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

#User Must place Email:
USER_EMAIL = 'user name should be given here'
USER_PASSWORD = 'password should be here'

emailField = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='email']")))
emailField.clear()
emailField.send_keys(USER_EMAIL)
submitEmail= WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']"))).click()
#Dismiss "It looks like this email is used with more than one account from Microsoft" screen
#personalAccount = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[id='msaTile']"))).click()

#Enter Password
passwordField = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='password']")))
passwordField.clear()
passwordField.send_keys(USER_PASSWORD)
submitPassword = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.table-row"))).click()
time.sleep(30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSubmit_SAOTCC_Continue"))).click()
#Dismiss StaySignedIn
staySignedIn = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[id='idBtn_Back']"))).click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[title='Calendar']"))).click()
printBtn1 = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button[contains(@role,'menuitem')=false]"))).click()
```

Comment: Weird, I just tried what you said: `WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button[contains(@class,'action')]"))).click()` right after opening the print popup and still not printing/clicking.

Comment: was there any exception ?

Comment: Yeah here's the exception:    `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed' `

Comment: This is not the right error stack trace for my code, you must be having `is_displayed` somewhere else in your code too, and that is causing the failure

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXTbrY7Tj5J9ixXTxcfJaAm_tI4jB4ma/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And here is the line right before your code: `printBtn2 = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[id='id__98']"))).click()`

Comment: Check where you have this line `span[id='id__98']`

Comment: Where it suppose to click `printBtn2 = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[id='id__98']"))).click()` ?

Comment: This is used right before your code, so on the print button right before the final popup with Print & Cancel.

Comment: It clicks the second print button (on the screen right before final screen)

Comment: I have given you this code `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button"))).click()` to click on print button which is in the top right corner, please utilize the code given above

Comment: I've just added it.

Comment: Did it fail again ?

Comment: No, the print never occurred even with these changes

Comment: Can you share your code through any .text file using any free file hosting website

Comment: Sure, one moment

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AptKzEGtMHcCSI2WvWpvmWij9xWWX-9Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you are trying to run this, note that the code at the two "dismiss" comments may not apply to you, and if so you can delete it if you'd like to test this on your own machine

Comment: I wonder why your script did not fail at this line `submitPassword = WebDriverWait(driver,40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[type='submit']"))).click()` ?

Comment: I mean I certainly don’t have your level of experience in Selenium, so my logic is likely flawed. But when I used Inspect Element, I was able to get the CSS class input, and the input whose type property=submit. What makes you feel that this code is unlikely to work?

Comment: I can not debug that why it is working, ideally it should not, cause we have 2 matching nodes in DOM. Anyway I figured it out, I provided you this line in my original post `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Print']/ancestor::button[contains(@class,'action')]"))).click()`  I guess you did not use it. Now see above I have updated the entire code above. There is time.sleep(30) to just give OTP when it asked, and it should do the magic. Also do not forget to give your creds as well

Comment: Vscode is not recognizing time.sleep() for some reason

Comment: There is a import for that `import time`

Comment: Rookie mistake.

Comment: Program never passes stay signed in

Comment: for that you need session cookies, but that's a off topic question for this ticket.

Comment: But what is the click on div.table-row and idSubmit_SAOTCC_Continue supposed to do

Comment: It is to click on the telephone number which is shown as +91-XXXXX at my end. for you it may be different based on your location

Comment: I see, so that might not be relevant for my implementation